# What does 厉害 mean, and in what context does it mean what?

Tags: mandarin, expressions, meaning

This has to be one of the more ambiguous words I have struggled with.

厉害 can be:

- *very well performed* = 玩得很厉害;
- *harsh* = 骂得很厉害;
- *severe* = 生病得很厉害;
- probably a bunch of other stuff...

Can anyone give a comprehensive summary of the meanings and related contexts?

Comment: not ambiguous, just too many meanings (like the words `great`, `like` if you look up their entries in a dictionary) :p

Comment: Don't forget that 厉害 can be easily confused with 利害 which sounds exactly the same and means `pros and cons`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is somewhat similar in usage to the word `great` in English, with the following meanings I can recall:

**Impressive** or **skilled**:

> 他的功夫非常厉害。= *He is very skilled in martial arts.*
>
> 太厉害了，他是怎么做到的？ = *Very impressive, how did he manage to achieve that?*

**formidable**:

> 厉害的角色 = *A formidable figure (not one to be messed around with)*
>
> 厉害的手段 = *formidable tactics (in a sporting game, or as part of political intrigue)*

**severe**:

> 某某股跌得太厉害了 = *Stock X has taken a severe fall (in value)*

However, 厉害 is not usually the phrase/word of choice to describe a performance (of the arts).

Comment: I think when 厉害 is used to describe the performance, it means "to be skillful to do, to be good at something, as you mentioned. I would say "他的三分球很厉害" *He is good at three-point shot* (as in basketball).

Comment: That is true but I have this feeling that it is turning into an often-abused word (just like `great` and `like` in English) used by people are unable or too lazy to think of a more appropriate word.

Answer (score 3):

prusswan's answer is great.I just want  to make a supplement . 厉害 can be a noun and means

> harsh(or severe) means(or way,manoeuvre,measure,etc.)

Example:

> 看来我得让你看看我的厉害。
>   *It seems that I should make you know my severe means.*

This is a warning to the listener that you will do something bad to him.

Comment: You have an example sentence of when it is a noun?

Comment: @LarsAndren Ok, I added an example to the answer.

Comment: Very interesting example! Two excellent answers, wish I could choose both as the correct answer.

Comment: @LarsAndren You may suggest this on meta. Well, just kidding. I think prusswan's answer is better since it's more comprehensive. For me, the up-vote is enough.

Answer (score 2):

厉害 can also mean quite a few things when describing a person and relies heavily on the context. For example the sentence:

> 他是很厉害

Has numerous possibilities and it would be wrong to assume something without further explanation.

Some examples:

- This person is very strict or harsh
- This person has a sharp personality
- This person is very skillful / capable

The same with the use of 太厉害. This could have a positive or negative connotation. It could describe someone who is amazingly skillful or someone that is overly strict.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of ambiguity I was talking about. Great addition

Answer (score 2):

An idiomatic English translation of 厉害 might be something like "beast" or "monster." Such a person might be "very capable." Or else overly harsh, strict, or overbearing. But basically "out of control."

Answer (score 2):

'厲害' could be either 'Well/Good/impressive' or 'serious'.

Example:
'好厲害!' -- 'Impressive/Good/Well done!'.
'也病的太厲害了吧' -- 'Well, but, ain't that a kinda serious sick?'.

Answer (score -1):

I have been quite busy preparing for my Test of Chinese as a Foreign Language (TOCFL) exam, a Mandarin certification exam held twice annually. There are five levels and I started from the third level. [Translator in Beijing](http://vivitranslation.com/interpreting/beijing-interpreting.html)

Comment: Lovely answer to another question.